# How to set BOOL value TRUE on button click

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS development.
I have declared a `BOOL` variable as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL eventCheck;
```

and set this variable's value to `YES` but I am not getting how to execute my code on click of a `button` whose `BOOL` value is YES.
Please help me out.

Comment: Look at that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428468/how-do-i-name-and-link-an-ibaction-button-created-in-a-storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard you can Ctrl-drag an IBAction method to your class, the IDE should help you in doing that or you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428468/how-do-i-name-and-link-an-ibaction-button-created-in-a-storyboard) as Azat said.

If you are doing programatically first you need to set a selector for that button, which is the one who is going to handle the touch action

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And the selector (or ctrl-dragged) method should be something like

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched: (id Sender) {
   NSLog(@"touch action");
   self.eventCheck = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer but this is honestly all very well documented.

First you have to make a tap (not click - we don't click on iOS) gesture recognizer and add it to your button:

```
[myButton addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonHandlerFunction:)]];
```

Then you make the function to handle the tap:

```
- (void)myButtonHandlerFunction:(UIButton *)button
{
  eventCheck = !eventCheck;
}
```

We were all new at iOS programming once (except maybe the Mac programmers because it's very close) so there's some sympathy. Still, it's really important to read the documentation, the tutorials, and to learn how things work. It will make your life easier in the long-run than asking basic questions here.