# Buttons/Links under view object in .xib file are not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

Can somebody tell me why none of the buttons under the "License Agreement View" UIView object in my .xib file are triggering an action?  It seems that the Scrollview object is messing up the behavior.  When the buttons are directly under the "Scroll View" object (as opposed to the "License Agreement View" UIView object), then they function properly.  But, I need to group my buttons under the UIViews as shown in the view hierarchy below.

**Here's the view layout:**

[image]

**Here's my view hierarchy:**

[image]

**Here's the corresponding .m file:**

```
@interface MYViewController ()
     - (IBAction)licenseAgreementPressed:(id)sender;
     - (IBAction)legalDisclaimerPressed:(id)sender;
     - (IBAction)privacyStatementPressed:(id)sender;

     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *licenseAgreementView;
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *legalDisclaimerButton;
     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *privacyStatementButton;
@end

@implementation MYViewController
- (IBAction)licenseAgreementPressed:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Pressed A");
}

- (IBAction)legalDisclaimerPressed:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Pressed B");
}

- (IBAction)privacyStatementPressed:(id)sender 
{
     NSLog(@"Pressed C");
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you connect the ibaction properly ?Is the view loaded ? Did you set the file owner of the view ? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the links, buttons, and text fields were not actually located within the bounds specified the parent views because the original .xib file didn't have the required constraints pinned to those elements.  I discovered this by checking the "clip to bounds" checkbox in the Attributes Inspector pane.  Whenever "clip to bounds" was checked, the app was NOT displaying any of the above view objects; I could only see links, buttons, and text fields when "clip to bounds" was unchecked but unfortunately, those elements were not clickable at that point.  After setting the necessary constraints, however, the view elements were correctly placed within the bounds of their parent views and the text fields, labels, and buttons became clickable.  I'm attaching the constraints that I used to fix the problem.  Note: the constraints that are not expanded only include a height constraint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have made connection between IBAction(code) and UIButton(in xib) , please check this post [How do I name and link an IBAction button created in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428468/how-do-i-name-and-link-an-ibaction-button-created-in-a-storyboard)

Comment: The connections are fine.  Please see updated question for more info.  Thx!

Comment: It doesn't matter under which view hierarchy  you lay the buttons ,if the connections are right it should work

Comment: Also make sure that no other view overlays such that button interaction is disabled . check https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6 how

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that tutorial before as well.  It's almost like "License Agreement View" is covering up the button underneath.  I tried to programmatically  add   [self.scrollView sendSubviewToBack:self.licenseAgreementView]; but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect your actions to the elements in interface builder by control-dragging it?
If your actions are connected you will see a little filled out circle  on the left of the line in your editor. [image: circles]
Check [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html) for further information on how to connect your storyboard elements to your code.

Comment: Yup, they are connected properly.  Please see updated question for more info.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It is because none of the buttons are *inside the bounds* of the license agreement view. A button outside its superview's bounds is untappable.

Comment: Can you explain some more please and/or provide an example of a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: _You_ are the one who is not showing a screenshot of a running app, or your xib file, and not explaining how these views get _sized_ when they are put into the interface. _You_ need to do the explaining, not me.